# Increasing size of chart inside pop-up window - Leaflet - d3.js?

Tags: leaflet, popup, chart, d3

I have created a chart inside a pop-up window for a marker on leaflet javascript. I am new to html, css, and javascript. I have also used d3js for the plot. The problem is that I cannot increase the plot size inside the window (in this case, only the width) to cover the entire window. I have used a long series of values (for my graph) since it may be possible in real data when one wants to create some charts.

I want the graph to be horizontally stretched so that the bars are wider. The data that I want to use is quite long.

[image]

I have attached the entire code so that it can be tested easily.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Leaflet Map Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        #map { height: 800px; }

        .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
            width: 600px !important;
            height: 200px !important;
        }

        .leaflet-popup-content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/leaflet-geoserver-request-master/leaflet-geoserver-request-master/src/L.Geoserver.js"></script>

<script>
    // Initialize the map


    var map = L.map('map').setView([35.5, 23.92], 11); // Centered at (latitude, longitude) and zoom level

    var googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
    }).addTo(map)



var geojsonFeature = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Sample Location",
        "chartData": [20, 30, 40, 10, 50, 20, 30, 40, 10, 50, 20, 30, 40, 10, 50, 20, 30, 40, 10, 50, 30, 40, 10, 50] // Sample chart data
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [23.7, 35.4]
      }
    };


// ... (previous Leaflet and GeoJSON setup)

L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.chartData) {
      layer.bindPopup(function (layer) {
        var popupContent = document.createElement('div');
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 400; // Adjust as needed
        canvas.height = 200; // Adjust as needed
        popupContent.appendChild(canvas);

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: ['A','B', 'C' ,'D' ,'E' ,'F', 'G' ,'H' ,'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M' ,'N', 'O' ,'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T' ,'U' ,'V' ,'W', 'X' ,'Y', 'Z'],
            datasets: [{
              label: 'Chart Data',
              data: feature.properties.chartData,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(120, 152, 35, 0.6)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }
        });


        return popupContent; // Return an empty string to prevent Leaflet from creating its own content
      });
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I know that the following lines change the size of the window. I have already increased it.

```
        .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
            width: 600px !important;
            height: 200px !important;
        }
```

I thought that the following lines would do the trick. However, when I tried to increase the percentage, nothing happened.

```
        .leaflet-popup-content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

Neither changes to the following lines worked.

```
        canvas.width = 500; // Adjust as needed
        canvas.height = 200; // Adjust as needed
```

Any idea what could I do to fix it?

Comment: Yes, I want the graph to be horizontally stretched so that the bars are wider. The data that I want to use is long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a bit of playing with browser debugger to find out what will make `chart.js` happy. The fact is that it modifies canvas attributes before drawing chart on it.

To get desired results, relevant part of CSS has to be modified like this:

```css
.leaflet-popup-content {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 90%;
}
```

Relevant part of JS has to be modified like this:

```
L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.chartData) {
      layer.bindPopup(function (layer) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        new Chart(canvas, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: ['A','B', 'C' ,'D' ,'E' ,'F', 'G' ,'H' ,'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M' ,'N', 'O' ,'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T' ,'U' ,'V' ,'W', 'X' ,'Y', 'Z'],
            datasets: [{
              label: 'Chart Data',
              data: feature.properties.chartData,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(120, 152, 35, 0.6)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }
        });
        return canvas;
      });
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Here is how the result looks like:

[image]

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/fgukvpbn/

Comment: I applied these two changes but it did not work (the chart is not wider). I tested in Chrome and Edge browser. Did you make any other changes?

Comment: Added working JSFiddle to the answer.